# Meaning of "But he and you between you have set me thinking"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, [Chapter XXV, passage 417/418](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_25), published 1892)

> It was now the turn of the captain, and there is no doubt he was no longer the man that we have seen; sudden relief, the sense of perfect safety, a square meal and a good glass of grog, had all combined to relax his vigilance and depress his energy.
>
> “When was this done?” asked the doctor, looking at the wound.
>
> “More than a week ago,” replied Wicks, thinking singly of his log.
>
> “Hey?” cried the doctor, and he raised his hand and looked the captain in the eyes.
>
> “I don't remember exactly,” faltered Wicks.
>
> And at this remarkable falsehood, the suspicions of the doctor were at once quadrupled.
>
> “By the way, which of you is called Wicks?” he asked easily.
>
> “What's that?” snapped the captain, falling white as paper.
>
> “Wicks,” repeated the doctor; “which of you is he? that's surely a plain question.”
>
> Wicks stared upon his questioner in silence.
>
> “Which is Brown, then?” pursued the doctor.
>
> “What are you talking of? what do you mean by this?” cried Wicks, snatching his half-bandaged hand away, so that the blood sprinkled in the surgeon's face.
>
> He did not trouble to remove it. Looking straight at his victim, he pursued his questions. “Why must Brown go the same way?” he asked.
>
> Wicks fell trembling on a locker. “Carthew's told you,” he cried.
>
> “No,” replied the doctor, “he has not. **But he and you between you have set me thinking**, and I think there's something wrong.”
>
> “Give me some grog,” said Wicks. “I'd rather tell than have you find out. I'm damned if it's half as bad as what any one would think.”
>
> And with the help of a couple of strong grogs, the tragedy of the *Flying Scud* was told for the first time.

I have an issue with the wording **between you** in the sentence "But he and you **between you** have set me thinking". I suspect it to be an obsolete wording and means "collectively": "But he and you collectively have set me thinking", as in sentences like

[The imperial dictionary of the English language by John Ogilvie](https://archive.org/details/imperialdictinew01ogiluoft/page/264/mode/2up?q=between)

> 5. Pertaining to, in the power of, or by the action of two together, or one or other of two; as,
>
> > *The blame of this lies between you.*
> >
> > *You must get that done between you.*
> >
> > *They had the watch between them.*

Comment: There's a nursery rhyme: "Jack Sprat could eat no fat, his wife could eat no lean / and so **between them both**, you see, they licked the platter clean." In a sense, the task (of eating fat and lean meat) was divided "between" the two people.

Comment: @AndyBonner I don't think I got the memo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, funnily enough, it isn't obsolete.

It can be used two ways and remain idiomatic:

**You and he between you** have caused a lot of trouble on the farm.

OR

**Between you, you and he** have caused a lot of trouble on the farm.

ALSO
**You have caused a lot of trouble between you**.
**Between you, you have caused a lot of trouble**.

[you is plural in English in the last two examples]

And we would *never say* "collectively" for two people.